# Percentage append next to value counts in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, append, percentage

I'm trying to create a excel with value counts and percentage, I'm almost finishing but when I run my for loop, the percentage is added like a new df.to_frame with two more columns but I only want one this is how it looks in excel:

I want that the blue square not appears in the excel or the df and the music percentage is next to the counts of music column, also the music percentage I would like to put it with percentage format instead 0.81 --> 81%. Below is my code.

[image]

```
li = []

for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    value_counts = df.iloc[:, i].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
    value_percentage = df.iloc[:, i].value_counts(normalize=True).to_frame().reset_index()#.style.format('{:.2%}')
    li.append(value_counts)
    li.append(value_percentage)

data = pd.concat(li, axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example (a few rows of your dataframe) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.reset_index()` function creates a column in your dataframe called index. So you are appending two-column dataframes each time, one of which is the index. You could add `.drop(columns='index')` after `.reset_index()` to drop the index column at each step and therefore also in your final dataframe.

However, depending on your application you may want to be careful with resetting the index because it looks like you are appending in a way where your rows do not align (i.e. not all your index columns are not all the same).

To change your dataframe values to strings with percentages you can use:

`value_counts = (value_counts*100).astype(str)+'%'`

Comment: Thanks it is like I wanted. 
To use just 2 decimals will be like this? 
"{:.2f}".format(round(a, 2))
and the is a way to add after the name of the column a %?

Comment: you don't need to round if you're using {:.2f}. Renaming columns: df = df.rename(columns={'old_name':'old_name'+' %'})

Comment: I tried with this formula but didn't work

value_percentage = "{:.2f}".format(float(value_percentage))